# How to plot a daily signal on a weekly chart?

Tags: pine-script

I want to plot a 50 day simple moving average on a weekly chart. I can determine which timeframe is currently displayed. If it's weekly, I could take a close interval: 50/7 equals about 7 weekly bars, but values would not be accurate. Is there a way to plot accurate daily SMA on a weekly chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One weekly bar can only show one of the daily values present in the *n* daily bars of the daily dilation of a weekly bar. You can use this:

```
plot(security(syminfo.tickerid, "D", sma(close,50)))
```

which, on a weekly chart, will show the value of the daily ma on the last day of the preceding week.

Comment: No way to get daily averages for each weekly bar and plot more accurately?

Comment: There are 5 or 7 daily average values in **each** weekly bar. Supposing you had access to all of them, how are you planning to plot them on that **one** weekly bar, or how would you use them in calculations? Perhaps I'm missing something, but I don't see how that will be useful. If you're really interested in exploring the intrabar route, see [our FAQ entry here](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#is-it-possible-to-use-security-on-lower-intervals-than-the-charts-current-interval) but I doubt you'll get anywhere useful with it. In any case, be sure you understand the compromises involved.